# What counts/should count as a "search hit" on CVs?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs

In the past few days that I've had [my CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/kyle) up I've received 8 search hits on my CV. In order to get a better idea of who visits my CV and when, I've embedded a few 1x1 transparent GIFs, one of which is at the top of my personal statement and appears in the search blurb. Of those 8 "search hits", only one actually loaded the image. Either the rest of the employers disabled loading of external images or my CV never actually appeared on the page.

Assuming this is the case, is it really fair to call them "search hits" when, by all accounts, the employer isn't even aware that you exist? It does give some idea as to how many searches have been done where you would be in the results, but I feel that ultimately it doesn't accurately reflect when a candidate's info is seen by an employer.

Should "search hits" be altered to reflect the candidate's info actually loading on the employer's computer? Should a different stat be added instead to capture this information? Or is this information even relevant/needed, given that it's possible to obtain through embedding an external image?

Comment: 1x1 transparent GIF hax!

Comment: lol at the GIF hack - nice workaround.  Now how to attach google analytics to it...

Comment: @Pollyanna: we should start a `feature-request` to allow us to put random HTML/JavaScript in our CVs. That would be pretty sweet.

Comment: If I were a employer and found out that you try to track me with a 1x1 transparent GIF, that would be definitely a **no hire**!

Comment: @John: Whoa, really? I honestly didn't think it was a big deal. Plenty of sites track visitors and this isn't really any different.

Comment: @Kyle: Yeah, and plenty of filters exist to get rid of these trackers. Guess why!

Comment: @John: If I had my resume/CV on my personal domain, wouldn't it be understood that I would log and monitor the attention it's getting? Is this situation different because it's not on a personal domain?

Comment: @Kyle: Even if it is your personal domain, I would not like it. These GIFs are like stalkers. You want to track more privacy information than you have to. Even people less paranoid than I am hate this. Consider that an employment is a matter of trust. You have to trust the employer, the employer has to trust you. How do you want to start mutual trust, when you spy him from the beginning?

Comment: If I was an employer, I'd commend you for your excellent idea and inquisitive look at how the system works.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to search hits, you should also see "Employer Views of Your CV" which gives you the information you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that statistic. I'm looking for a stat where my CV was presented on the page to the employer as a search result. For example, search for CVs in NYC and my "search hits" goes up, regardless of whether or not the employer actually saw it as a result. Instead I would like to see the number of times my CV result appeared on the page that the employer was viewing.

Comment: So... you want to know how many times a link to your CV was rendered?  The two results show when your CV was part of a search result set, and when an employer saw the CV, but you want the inbetween count - when they not only had you in their result set, but the result set shown to them onscreen included the link to your CV?  I guess I don't see the advantage.  Maybe you're trying to optimize your blurb so it attracts more employers to click?

Comment: If you're turning up in the search results but never make it to the employer's screen, there's something wrong. For example, it could indicate that your location/favorites/etc are too generic. Also, if you're appearing on the employer's screens but they're not clicking to see your full CV, then you may want to work on your personal statement/SO reputation/gravatar/etc to see if you can get a higher click-through. There are uses to this information and as a paying member of SO careers it would be great if I didn't have to create it myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact how the statistic already works.

If you are RENDERED ON THE SEARCH RESULT PAGE, the counter is incremented.

It is a per-page setting so I can't guarantee that they scrolled all the way down, but if you're on the SERP, that's the only way that counter gets incremented. Verified.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I *thought* it worked, but my image was only loaded once for 8 (now 9) search hits. Are you blocking images in the search results now?

Answer (score 0):

The image markdown probably does not render in search results. Go to `Employer View/How your CV will appear in employer search results` and check for yourself.

Comment: It does appear in the "employer view" for me, but in the actual search interface it's replaced with `<link temporarily hidden>">`.

Comment: Edit: images defined with <img src="..."> appear in both sections, ones defined with ![markdown] appear only in the second one. Strange.