# Careers: Did you notice the number of job searches is 10 times the number of employers at all times?

Tags: discussion, jobs

It is maybe just an interesting coincidence, but the number of resume searches keeps constantly at almost exactly the number of emplyoers. If the site in use the number of searches should be more closely corelated to half of square root of employers times constant, probably those 10. It seems almost like employers would just test the site a bit each and then stop using it. Do you think it is because the site is still in beta or would it be a sign of some problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These stats are valid - it's just coincidence, however it is an interesting observation.

Comment: Mine were right at 10% for a while, and over the last week or two they've gone down to 8%. /sad.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have Geoff check, but the stats should be valid!

(no, we do not have a "# of employers * 10" algorithm in place, although that would be funny.. sort of.. I guess)

Comment: I don't think you have that in place, but does Global Search mean the employer creates a search and then runs it multiple times and it counts as one or every time they search it counts as one? If the former, the number is fine, every employer has about 10 "interests" and they search for those. If it is the later, it would mean they just search 10 times and stop using the site, which would be sign of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that when [I posted a screenshot to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/what-counts-should-count-as-a-search-hit-on-cvs/32615#32615), but the numbers changed and it was no longer true (at least for the moment).

It is certainly an interesting correlation, but after some observation one finds that it's provably false.